# GNU Octave, how to stop 3d axis from resizing while rotating in the interactive window?

Tags: octave

Question: Is there a way to stop octave from trying to auto-fit the axis object into a constant size box and instead leave the viewing scale constant?

I like to show my students lots of 3D plots relating to various math/science topics, and to use the default interactive window (Octave 4.0 through Debian amd64 repositories) to rotate the figure live during class. Problem is the resulting resizing is distracting to the shape of the object/animated-trajectories.

Here is a simple scatter plot animation I am working with but this applies to all 3d plots.

```
#!/usr/bin/octave-cli

clear all;
close all;


planetx=[-0.1478672,  -0.7257694,  -0.1756896,   1.3832219;
 -0.0381809,  -0.7160833,  -0.2610456,   1.3850799;
  0.0737428, -0.6924100,  -0.3444268 ,  1.3831345;
  0.1793219,  -0.6552495,  -0.4251856 ,  1.3774159;
  0.2688712,  -0.6053663,  -0.5026964,   1.3679664;
  0.3311067,  -0.5437714,  -0.5763614,  1.3548404;
  0.3531110,  -0.4716991,  -0.6456154 , 1.3381034;
  0.3219212,  -0.3905812,  -0.7099307,  1.3178316;
  0.2300102,  -0.3020162,  -0.7688217,  1.2941111;
  0.0855329,  -0.2077379,  -0.8218485,  1.2670372;
 -0.0814988,  -0.1095802,  -0.8686203,  1.2367138;
 -0.2318261,  -0.0094427,  -0.9087983,  1.2032523;
 -0.3384457,   0.0907458,  -0.9420979,  1.1667714;
 -0.3929915,   0.1890627,  -0.9682904,  1.1273956;
 -0.3988960,   0.2836267,  -0.9872039,  1.0852552;
 -0.3641642,   0.3726316,  -0.9987242,  1.0404850;
 -0.2977153,   0.4543788,  -1.0027945,  0.9932238;
 -0.2081496,   0.5273076,  -0.9994152,  0.9436139;
 -0.1036023,   0.5900227,  -0.9886429,  0.8917999;
  0.0079838,   0.6413199,  -0.9705888,  0.8379287];

planety=[-0.4466930,  -0.0252958,   0.9659716,  -0.0238017;
 -0.4657149,  -0.1263067,   0.9471212,   0.0520870;
 -0.4508105,  -0.2248822,   0.9208844,   0.1278263;
 -0.4013623,  -0.3190893,   0.8874673,   0.2032115;
 -0.3181219 , -0.4070912,   0.8471345,   0.2780418;
 -0.2041932 , -0.4871833,   0.8002063,   0.3521215;
 -0.0669533,  -0.5578254,   0.7470558,   0.4252601;
  0.0789006,  -0.6176696,   0.6881051,   0.4972739;
  0.2085279,  -0.6655848,   0.6238214,   0.5679859;
  0.2899490,  -0.7006754,   0.5547124,   0.6372265;
  0.2993354,  -0.7222964,   0.4813220,   0.7048344;
  0.2378102,  -0.7300623,   0.4042244,   0.7706562;
  0.1278686,  -0.7238523,   0.3240197,   0.8345477;
 -0.0036336,  -0.7038105,   0.2413281,   0.8963733;
 -0.1357070,  -0.6703412,   0.1567847,   0.9560064;
 -0.2544710,  -0.6241000,   0.0710340,   1.0133298;
 -0.3512399,  -0.5659813,  -0.0152755,   1.0682353;
 -0.4205857,  -0.4971011,  -0.1014962,   1.1206241;
 -0.4590497,  -0.4187770,  -0.1869867,   1.1704064;
 -0.4644300,  -0.3325042,  -0.2711164,   1.2175012];

planetz=[ -2.3139e-02,   4.1378e-02,   2.0503e-04,  -3.4412e-02;
 -3.4756e-02,   3.9440e-02,   2.0468e-04,  -3.2867e-02;
 -4.3806e-02,   3.6728e-02,   2.0433e-04,  -3.1231e-02;
 -4.9452e-02,   3.3297e-02,   2.0398e-04,  -2.9511e-02;
 -5.0867e-02,   2.9217e-02,   2.0363e-04,  -2.7710e-02;
 -4.7267e-02,   2.4568e-02,   2.0328e-04,  -2.5834e-02;
 -3.8071e-02,   1.9444e-02,   2.0292e-04,  -2.3890e-02;
 -2.3288e-02,   1.3946e-02,   2.0256e-04,  -2.1882e-02;
 -4.2578e-03,   8.1806e-03,   2.0220e-04,  -1.9816e-02;
  1.5659e-02,   2.2609e-03,   2.0183e-04,  -1.7700e-02;
  3.1762e-02,  -3.6987e-03,   2.0145e-04,  -1.5537e-02;
  4.0539e-02,  -9.5832e-03,   2.0107e-04,  -1.3335e-02;
  4.1349e-02,  -1.5280e-02,   2.0067e-04,  -1.1099e-02;
  3.5618e-02,  -2.0679e-02,   2.0027e-04,  -8.8346e-03;
  2.5376e-02,  -2.5678e-02,   1.9986e-04,  -6.5487e-03;
  1.2491e-02,  -3.0182e-02,   1.9944e-04,  -4.2464e-03;
 -1.5080e-03,  -3.4104e-02,   1.9901e-04,  -1.9337e-03;
 -1.5389e-02,  -3.7371e-02,   1.9856e-04,   3.8413e-04;
 -2.8122e-02, -3.9918e-02,   1.9810e-04,   2.7015e-03;
 -3.8798e-02,  -4.1699e-02,   1.9762e-04,   5.0131e-03;];

N=size(planetx)
N=N(1,1)

figure('position',[50,50,1000,750]);
h=scatter3(planetx(1,:),planety(1,:),planetz(1,:) , 10*[3,4,5,4], 
[3,4,5,4],'filled');

axis([-2,2,-2,2,-1,1],'square');
set(gca,'fontsize',20)
axis('manual')
#box('off')
#axis('off')
view([15,15]);
hold on;

p1=plot3(planetx(1:20,1),planety(1:20,1),planetz(1:20,1),':')
p2=plot3(planetx(1:20,2),planety(1:20,2),planetz(1:20,2),':')
p3=plot3(planetx(1:20,3),planety(1:20,3),planetz(1:20,3),':')
p4=plot3(planetx(1:20,4),planety(1:20,4),planetz(1:20,4),':')

ans=input('loaded, hit enter to start!')

for i=1:N
    #[AZ,EL]=view();
    set(h, 'xdata', planetx(i,:) , 'ydata', planety(i,:), 'zdata', 
    planetz(i,:))
    title(sprintf('YEAR=%f',2000+i*200/14010 ))

    set(p1,'xdata',planetx(1:i,1),'ydata',planety(1:i,1),'zdata', planetz(1:i,1))
    set(p2, 'xdata', planetx(1:i,2),'ydata',planety(1:i,2),'zdata',planetz(1:i,2))
    set(p3, 'xdata', planetx(1:i,3),'ydata',planety(1:i,3),'zdata',planetz(1:i,3))
    set(p4, 'xdata', planetx(1:i,4),'ydata',planety(1:i,4),'zdata',planetz(1:i,4))
    pause(1)
endfor;
ans=input('hit to close!')
```

Comment: No. In general you need to specify the axis within the for loop whenever you call a new plot command. You're using local data, so I can't test what you mean exactly, but I'm assuming that when you `set(h, xdata, ...)` it resets the axis? In which case, the new axis can also be set via this syntax; just set the `xlim` `ylim` and `zlim` parameters at the same time as you set the `xdata` etc.

Comment: Thank you, sorry about the local data, I added some numbers for a complete simulation. The problem is not resetting the axis limits themselves, that is ensured by `axis('manual')`, and `set('xdata'...)` doesn't create a new plot but just changes the data for an existing axis object. The issue is that when you manipulate the plot window with a click and drag rotation it changes the apparent size depending on the viewing angle. The effect is that while rotating it makes you feel like you are changing the viewing distance from the image. It makes sense for maximizing the used window area.

Comment: Maybe that's a bug on the old octave versions ... on my installation (octave 4.2.1 on linux) it works as you would expect. Might I suggest using `octave` rather than `octave-cli` on your crunchbang syntax though, as the former defaults to gnuplot mode, whereas the latter defaults to the much more versatile qt mode. Not sure if that's related to your issue or not though.

Comment: I added a gif of what this looks like on my system, just to confirm we're talking about the same thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems this may be a bug of older octave versions.
On my system (octave 4.2.1 - linux) it seems to work as you expect it should.

[image]

---

<sub>PS. ignore the glitches, they're bugs related to the screen recorder I used</sub>

---

**UPDATE**: In response to the comment by Cris, it may be that what Robert was referring to was how the camera seems to 'zoom out' slightly in order to accommodate the full 'box' when one rotates.

You can change this behaviour by changing the cameraviewanglemode property from 'auto' to 'manual'. This results in a smoother rotating experience without the camera moving from its place.

```
>> set(gca, 'cameraviewanglemode', 'manual')
```

Visual comparison:

[image]
[image]

'auto mode' vs 'manual mode'

---

The other 'camera' related properties may be useful to play around with as well. Type `get(gca, 'camera')` to get a list of relevant properties. (or just have a look at [this page](https://octave.org/doc/interpreter/Axes-Properties.html) in the manual for defaults etc).

Comment: Don't you notice how the axes change size as you rotate? It tries to fit the box + decorations inside the window, so then your point of view is along the box diagonal, it needs to scale it down significantly w.r.t. the point of view perpendicular to one face. Maybe this is "what you expect", because MATLAB does the same, but it is annoying anyway.

Comment: @CrisLuengo Aaaaah, now I see what you're referring to. The way it kinda "zooms out" when you move up because it tries to keep the axis limits specified still within view. You think this is what Robert is on about as well? I thought he was talking about `axis` resizing, i.e. the programmatic concept itself, not in the visual sense. You can control this using camera options. I think what you're referring to in particular is the cameraviewanglemode property.

Comment: That was my first impression on reading this question, because I've been annoyed with it as well in the past (using MATLAB). But it has never frustrated me enough to actually figure out how to avoid it. :)

Comment: Cool that it's such a simple solution. I'll have to remember this!

Comment: Cris, that is what I was referring too! And Tasos that solution is EXACTLY what I was trying to figure out how to accomplish, Thank you!